# inet_ntop and IPv6 addresses and PHP 5.5

Tags: php, ipv6, inet-ntop

I have an error with PHP 5.5 that does not occured with PHP5.3 and 5.4.
With IPv6 addresses, the function inet_ntop() throws me an error:

> Invalid in_addr value.

You can look at my work on [Github](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/SpomkyIpFilterBundle) (function is in [Network.php, line 88](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/SpomkyIpFilterBundle/blob/master/Tool/Network.php#L88)).
You can also look at the test job on [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/Spomky-Labs/SpomkyIpFilterBundle/jobs/19137847)

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The note in the docs may be pertinent: _if PHP was built with IPv6 support enabled_

Comment: What is the data you passed to this function? Include the function (it's a one-liner!) and its argument here; there was no reason to link to github.

Comment: The called function is `getIPv6Range('fe80::10/64')`. The function should return an array with the first and last address of the network. I transform this parameter to get the IP and mask in binary and then get the result (`'fe80::'` and `'fe80::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff'`). I have the same problem with other data sets and PHP5.5, but works fine with other versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I did not use the function properly and it was sending malformed data.
Works fine now, you can look at the corrected class [here](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/SpomkyIpFilterBundle/blob/master/Tool/Network.php)

Anyway, thank you for your answers.